# spring amqp listener: have to import the context?

Tags: spring-amqp

I am using spring rabbitmq, in the main function of the entry class I defined the following which will start the app.

```
public class TutorialListenerContainer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext c1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbit-listener-context.xml");
    }
}
```

That rabbit-listener-context.xml defined rabbitmq information, and then I defined the following to consume the message in rabbitmq. Looks like I have to import the xml configuration again to get the bean information. What's the best way to do avoid double import?

```
public class TutorialListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
       ApplicationContext c1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rabbit-listener-context.xml");
       .....
    }
```

Comment: NEVER create a new instance of the application context especially not that way. Unless ofcourse you want memory problems, performance issue, strange database concurrency issues, probable database connection starvation etc. If you want a bean use dependency injection that is the whole point of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject relevant context information(dependencies) to constructor of TutorialListener. You can do that using xml or @Configuration.